# ByteBuddy intercepting constructor arguments

Tags: byte-buddy, dynamic-class-creation

I am trying to dynamically create a class using ByteBuddy with my custom constructor.
I have read the [Intercepting default constructor with Byte Buddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907382/intercepting-default-constructor-with-byte-buddy) and I have written the following code base on that.

```
Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
                .name("foo").defineConstructor(Modifier.PUBLIC).withParameters(int.class)
                .intercept(
                        to(new Object() {
                            public void construct() throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("before constructor");
                            }
                        })
                        .andThen(MethodCall.invoke(Object.class.getConstructor()))
                        .andThen(to(new Object() {
                            public void construct() throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("after constructor");
                            }})
                        ))
                .make()
                .load(Main.class.getClassLoader(), INJECTION)
                .getLoaded();

        dynamicType.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(3);
```

My question is how can I access the integer argument of 'foo' constructor in the custom codes that I have added before and after calling the super constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, simply define a parameter with an annotation @Argument(0).

I'd recommend against using anonymous classes as their package-private visibility might render tricky outcomes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using annotations solved the problem.